# Django: Names are not showing in drop-down list

Tags: django

I need to show a list of countries for users to select from the ship's country field. But it's showing the Country object(1), Country object(2)... instead of showing names of countries

I've created classes for Ship and Country with the Ship class having a foreign key of country.

```
class Ship(models.Model):
    # Fields
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = extension_fields.AutoSlugField(populate_from='name', blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    callsign = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=4)

    # RelationShip Fields
    shipflag = models.ForeignKey(
        'manifest.Country', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        related_name="Ships", null=True
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.slug

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('manifest_Ship_detail', args=(self.slug,))

    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse('manifest_Ship_update', args=(self.slug,))
```

```
class Country(models.Model):

    # Fields
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = extension_fields.AutoSlugField(populate_from='name', blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    # RelationShip Fields
    continent = models.ForeignKey(
        'manifest.Continent',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="Countrys", 
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.slug

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('manifest_Country_detail', args=(self.slug,))

    def get_update_url(self):
    return reverse('manifest_Country_update', args=(self.slug,))
```

In the 'create new ship' form at the country dropdown combo I expect to see a list of countries like United States, Mexico, Canada... but instead am seeing countries as objects like this object(1), Country object(2)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add this method to your models. ;)

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```